# Calling a function repeatedly until its promise is resolved or until a set timeout has passed

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I have a function that results in a lot of errors so I have to call it many times before it finally gives the right result. It returns a promise so I created a wrapper around it that recursively keeps calling it upon rejection.

I want to return a [new Promise](http://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#new-promisefunctionfunction-resolve-function-reject-resolver---promise) created via [Bluebird](http://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#the-promiseinspection-interface) but which has to reject after a set timeout. And it has to keep calling that above function repeatedly. But before each repetition I want to check whether it was auto-rejected due to timeout.

[Bluebird](http://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#the-promiseinspection-interface) has a [`isRejected()`](http://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#the-promiseinspection-interface) method but it seems I can't use it from within the promise body:

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(reject, TIMEOUT*1000);
    return doSomethingWrapper();
    function doSomethingWrapper(){

        if(promise.isRejected()) return;
        // Error: Cannot read property 'isRejected' of undefined

        if(self.isRejected()) return;
        // Error: self.isRejected is not a function

        return doSomething().then(resolve, doSomethingWrapper).catch(doSomethingWrapper);
    }
});
```

Any other solution?

Comment: It doesn’t make sense to use it from within the promise body, and since `doSomethingWrapper` is called immediately, there is no way the `setTimeout` callback will have fired so it’s not necessary to check anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the timeout promise:

```
var timeout = Bluebird.delay(TIMEOUT * 1000).then(function () {
    return Bluebird.reject(new Error("Timed out"));
});
```

Create the operation promise:

```
var something = (function doSomethingWrapper() {
    if (timeout.isRejected()) {
        return;
    }

    return doSomething().catch(doSomethingWrapper);
})();
```

Race them:

```
var promise = Bluebird.race(something, timeout);
```

Answer (score 1):

This can actually be done in a simpler fashion:

```
Promise.try(function doSomethingWrapper(){ 
   return doSomething().catch(doSomethingWrapper); // retry
}).timeout(TIMEOUT * 1000);
```

No need for races :)

Comment: `timeout` does cancel the recursion? I didn't post this answer because I was not sure.